# Overleaf: Copying project (no changes) => References no longer shown

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I wanted to create a different version of a project and made a copy project in Overleaf.
I compiled the copied project, and the references aren't shown. I haven't touched any code/text yet, and I'm a beginner.

Edit: When I change "\bibliographystyle{apa}" to "\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}", it works. But in the original version, I am using apa. Why does that work in the original verison, but not in the copy?

Comment: IIRC Overleaf always runs new projects on the newest TeX live version that they have installed. It is very possible that your old project compiled file on an older TeX live version, but when you copy it, it is run on a newer version and errors. You can select the TeX live version you want to use in the menu (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version). Maybe you can find a working version. ...

Comment: ... If you want your code to work with the current TeX live installation on Overleaf, you ay want to have a look at the error messages to see what might be wrong. We can try to help you fix these errors, but of course you'd have to share with us what the errors are and ideally some code that reproduces them (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Answer (score 4):

New Overleaf projects (either created from scratch or when you clone a project) now use TeX Live 2020 (as of the time of writing). Some of the packages you use may have been updated in TL2020 to fix bugs etc, and so may behave differently.

In particular, the apa.bst file is no longer distributed in TeX Live 2020, so \bibliographystyle{apa} no longer works: therefore BibTeX can no longer process the .bib file.

If you want to continue to use apa.bst, you will need to manually upload a copy to your project. You can find it here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/apa.bst

Nevertheless, apa.bst is very old (it was last updated in 1992). It may be more sustainable to use a more modern implementation of APA style in your new documents (apacite or biblatex-apa).

Another alternative, if you want the new copy to be exactly the same as the original, is to change the TeX Live version on the copy to be the same as on your original project. You can learn more about how to view and change the TeX Live version here: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version.